# Jquery If Else Statement Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple buttons and when I click each one I want an element associated with that button to slide down and then when I click the same button the same element slides back up. The code below works but if I click one button it slides down then I click the second button nothing happens because it runs the else if part of the code. How would I fix this?

```
var moreOption = 1;
$(".more-button").click(function(){
        var buttonNumber = $(this).attr('buttonNumber');
        if (moreOption === 1) {
            $("#more"+buttonNumber).slideDown();
            moreOption = 2;
        } else if (moreOption === 2) {
            $("#more"+buttonNumber).slideUp();
            moreOption = 1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You cannot track status of two buttons with a single variable. You need one variable per button.

Comment: @jsalonen Yes, I know. How would I use a different variable for each button so a new button can easily be added? Thanks.

Comment: Use `$(this).data()` to track the value directly on the element, then it doesn't matter how many elements you have as they track themselves.   I'd go one step further and match your '#more' by data attributes rather than IDs as I don't generally agree with mixing IDs and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a data-attribute on the button and switch the state manually like this:

```
<button class="more-button" data-showMore="1" data-buttonNumber="1"/>

$(".more-button").click(function(){
        var buttonNumber = $(this).data('buttonNumber');
        var moreOption = $(this).data('showMore');
        if (moreOption == '1') {
            $("#more"+buttonNumber).slideDown();
            $(this).data('showMore', '2');
        } else if (moreOption == '2') {
            $("#more"+buttonNumber).slideUp();
            $(this).data('showMore', '1');
        }
    });
```

Comment: When running `alert($(this).data('buttonNumber'))` and `alert($(this).data('showMore'))` I get undefined.

Comment: I switched the `.data('foo')` for `.attr('data-foo')` and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @owwwerr which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @freedomn-m 2.2.4